# How to reduce memory usage? Problem from code forces

Tags: c++, memory-management

I solved this problem from codeforces: https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1471/B. But when I upload it it says memory limit exceeded. How can I reduce the memory usage? I used C++ for the problem. The problem was the following: "You have given an array a of length n and an integer x to a brand new robot. What the robot does is the following: it iterates over the elements of the array, let the current element be q. If q is divisible by x, the robot adds x copies of the integer qx to the end of the array, and moves on to the next element. Note that the newly added elements could be processed by the robot later. Otherwise, if q is not divisible by x, the robot shuts down.

Please determine the sum of all values of the array at the end of the process".

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector<int> vec;
    vector<int> ans;
    int temp;

    int t;
    cin >> t;
    int a = 0;
    int n, x;

    for(int i=0; i<t; i++){
            cin >> n >> x;
        while(a<n){
            cin >> temp;
            a++;
            vec.push_back(temp);
        }

        int q = 0;

        while(true){
            if(vec[q]%x == 0){
                for(int copies=0; copies<x; copies++){
                    vec.push_back(vec[q]/x);
                }
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
            q++;
        }

        int sum = 0;
        for(int z: vec){
            sum += z;
        }
        ans.push_back(sum);

        vec.clear();
        a = 0;
    }

    for(int y: ans){
        cout << y << endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to modify the array, you might reuse the initial array and have a counter to know from where you are.

Comment: What do you mean by a counter? Thanks for the response. I'm new to C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to build the array as specified to compute the sum

You might do:

```
int pow(int x, int n)
{
    int res = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
        res *= x;
    }
    return res;
}

int compute(const std::vector<int>& vec, int x)
{
    int res = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        const auto r = pow(x, i);
        for (auto e : vec) {
            if (e % r != 0) {
                return res;
            }
            res += e;
        }
        ++i;
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/efb63ea6ee619d5b)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I have one question: How can you make that code read the input? for example, if you input 2
1 2
12
4 2
4 6 8 2

Comment: You already have code to read input... not sure what you want...

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

- If you find an indivisible number in the original array, you're going to stop before you reach the numbers you have added (so they don't affect the result).
- If you add q/x to the array but q/x isn't divisible by x, you're going to stop there when you reach it, if you haven't already stopped earlier. (On the other hand, if q/x *is* divisible by x, the sum of x copies of q/x is q, so adding them is equivalent to adding q.)

So you don't need to expand the array, you just need to sum the elements and - on the side - keep the sum of all the numbers you would have expanded with until you find one that is not a multiple of x.
Then you either add that to the sum of the array or not, depending on whether you reached the end of the array.